# Unity List script field with +/- buttons in editor

Tags: unity, c#, editors

I am using Unity 2018.4.11f1 LTS. I have a script with a public `List<GameObject>` field.

In the property inspector, Unity provides a UI to this field where you specify the size of the list and then assign elements:

```
public List<GameObject> receivers;
```

[image]

My question is: Is there a way (perhaps a different field type) to have Unity provide an editor UI that consists of a +/- button where you can add and remove elements, rather than a list-size-based UI?

Something more along the lines of e.g. what it gives you for `UnityEvent`s:

[image]

Comment: Before anybody asks: I don't have any particular functional reason for wanting this UI, I just like it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [NaughtyAttributes](https://github.com/dbrizov/NaughtyAttributes)

> NaughtyAttributes is an extension for the Unity Inspector.
>
> It expands the range of attributes that Unity provides so that you can
> create powerful inspectors without the need of custom editors or
> property drawers. It also provides attributes that can be applied to
> non-serialized fields or functions.
>
> It is implemented by replacing the default Unity Inspector. This means
> that if you have any custom editors, NaughtyAttributes will not work
> with them. All of your custom editors and property drawers are not
> affected in any way.

#### ReorderableList

Provides array type fields with an interface for easy reordering of elements.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's *perfect*, thank you. And so naughty. My app feels devilishly NSFW now.